# What does output.check do in a .bst file?

Tags: bibtex

I've seen the function `output.check` used in .bst files a number of times; I'm sure I knew what it did at some point but I've now forgotten, and I can't easily find documentation that explains it (which presumably exists, but is buried in a bunch of resources which use it but don't say much about it.

In my (merlin-generated) .bst file, it reads

```
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
```

but most of that is unclear to me. What does this function do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Short version:

It checks if a required field is empty and issues a warning if so. To know which field you need to look at where the function is called. For instance, looking at the `article` function in `plain.bst`:

```
format.authors "author" output.check
```

This will check the author field and will print `empty author in <entry>` to the `blg` file.

#### Long version:

For instance, in the example above, the `format.authors` function is:

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}
```

It will leave either `"<Author-names>"` or `""` on the stack, depending if the `author` field was given. So, by now, our stack has as a (possibly empty) string. Now we insert a string `"author"` on the stack and call `output.check`.

`output.check` will do `'t :=`, which will put the topmost item of the stack (the literal string `"author"`) in the variable `'t`. Now we only have the (possibly empty) `"<Author-names>"` string on the stack.

Then we have `duplicate$`, which will make a copy of that, and then we have `empty$`, which will leave a logical `1` or `0` if that string of author names is empty.

The two conditional branches are inserted on the stack and consumed when the `if$` is called. The `if$` will check if the `empty$` returned `1` or `0` and will put the first or second branches on the stack accordingly.

If the `1` branch is taken, it means that the `author` field was not given, then we'll have `pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$` which will discard (now certainly) empty `"<Author-names>"` string and issue the warning. After that the execution continues normally.

If the `0` branch is taken, then `'output.nonnull` if called to print a (now certainly) *not* empty string.