# How to solve a "You can't pop an empty literal stack" error in custom BibTeX style?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, errors, stack

I have an issue that I know has been covered in other threads for specific examples but despite trying to track the issue down in the code myself, I am very new to using TeX so I've been unable to solve this. I have three references that throw up the above error when run using the `.bst` file below. It's worth noting that the journal I am submitting to did not have a function to correctly format `@inproceedings` so a colleague adjusted it for me.

As far as I'm aware, the only adjusted function was the `@inproceedings` one which was edited to be:

```
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title

     format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      end.quote.btitle 
    format.bvolume output.check
    format.edition output
    %"edition" bibinfo.check output
    format.date "year" output.check
    new.sentence
    %format.note output
    fin.entry
}
```

And the offical .bst file for the journal is available here:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/universal-manuscript-template-for-osa-journals/bccwtwxwjbvs

The references themselves have the format:

```
@inproceedings{Test2013,
    title = {{The title is here}},
    year = {2013},
    booktitle = {The proceedings title},
    author = {Author, Alan and Author, Barry},
    edition = {123456},
    volume = {789},
    doi = {10.1117/12.2024082},
    keywords = {keyword1,keyword2,keyword3}
}
```

As I said I'm totally lost with this so any help would be appreciated greatly.
Thank you.

Edit: to make it slightly easier, this is the `.bst` file I'm actually using:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    eid
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  skip$
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {non.stop}
{ duplicate$
   "}" * add.period$
   #-1 #1 substring$ "." =
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }
 % Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
 % Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
 %-------------------------------------------------------------------
 % Begin module:
 % \ProvidesFile{english.mbs}[2003/11/06 4.2 (PWD)]

 % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "eds." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "" }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "" }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "," }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pp." }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "p." }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chap." }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Tech. Rep." }

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "Ph.D. thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.first}
{ "1st" }

FUNCTION {bbl.second}
{ "2nd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.third}
{ "3rd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.fourth}
{ "4th" }

FUNCTION {bbl.fifth}
{ "5th" }

FUNCTION {bbl.st}
{ "st" }

FUNCTION {bbl.nd}
{ "nd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.rd}
{ "rd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.th}
{ "" }
FUNCTION {eng.ord}
{ duplicate$ "1" swap$ *
  #-2 #1 substring$ "1" =
     { bbl.th * }
     { duplicate$ #-1 #1 substring$
       duplicate$ "1" =
         { pop$ bbl.st * }
         { duplicate$ "2" =
             { pop$ bbl.nd * }
             { "3" =
                 { bbl.rd * }
                 { bbl.th * }
               if$
             }
           if$
          }
       if$
     }
   if$
}

MACRO {jan} {"Jan."}

MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}

MACRO {mar} {"Mar."}

MACRO {apr} {"Apr."}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"Jun."}

MACRO {jul} {"Jul."}

MACRO {aug} {"Aug."}

MACRO {sep} {"Sep."}

MACRO {oct} {"Oct."}

MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}

MACRO {dec} {"Dec."}

 % End module: english.mbs
%% Copyright 1994-2005 Patrick W Daly
MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Comput. Surv."}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Inf."}

MACRO {cacm} {"Commun. ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM J. Res. Dev."}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Syst.~J."}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Trans. Software Eng."}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Trans. Comput."}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Trans. Comput. Aid. Des."}

MACRO {ipl} {"Inf. Process. Lett."}

MACRO {jacm} {"J.~ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"J.~Comput. Syst. Sci."}

MACRO {scp} {"Sci. Comput. Program."}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM J. Comput."}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Trans. Comput. Syst."}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Trans. Database Syst."}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Trans. Graphic."}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Trans. Math. Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Trans. Office Inf. Syst."}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Trans. Progr. Lang. Syst."}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theor. Comput. Sci."}

FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      pop$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ pop$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.warn}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      swap$ "missing " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ "empty " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
STRINGS  { bibinfo}
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              numnames #2 >
              t "others" = not and
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
  format.names
}
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
}
FUNCTION {get.bbl.editor}
{ editor num.names$ #1 > 'bbl.editors 'bbl.editor if$ }

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "," *
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
      *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
        if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ }
  if$
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "\enquote{" swap$ *
      non.stop
        { ",} " * }
        { "} " * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {end.quote.title}
{ title empty$
    'skip$
    { before.all 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {end.quote.btitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    'skip$
    { editor empty$
        { before.all 'output.state := }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in
  " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{
  ""
  duplicate$ empty$
  year  "year"  bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { swap$ 'skip$
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      if$
      *
    }
    { swap$ 'skip$
        {
          swap$
          " " * swap$
        }
      if$
      *
    }
  if$
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    {
      before.all 'output.state :=
    " (" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
      "volume" bibinfo.check * *
      series "series" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { swap$ bbl.of space.word * swap$
          emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { number "number" bibinfo.check }
            { output.state mid.sentence =
                { bbl.number }
                { bbl.number capitalize }
              if$
              number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
              bbl.in space.word *
              series "series" bibinfo.check *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {is.num}
{ chr.to.int$
  duplicate$ "0" chr.to.int$ < not
  swap$ "9" chr.to.int$ > not and
}

FUNCTION {extract.num}
{ duplicate$ 't :=
  "" 's :=
  { t empty$ not }
  { t #1 #1 substring$
    t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
    duplicate$ is.num
      { s swap$ * 's := }
      { pop$ "" 't := }
    if$
  }
  while$
  s empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$ s }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {convert.edition}
{ extract.num "l" change.case$ 's :=
  s "first" = s "1" = or
    { bbl.first 't := }
    { s "second" = s "2" = or
        { bbl.second 't := }
        { s "third" = s "3" = or
            { bbl.third 't := }
            { s "fourth" = s "4" = or
                { bbl.fourth 't := }
                { s "fifth" = s "5" = or
                    { bbl.fifth 't := }
                    { s #1 #1 substring$ is.num
                        { s eng.ord 't := }
                        { edition 't := }
                      if$
                    }
                  if$
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  t
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      convert.edition
      output.state mid.sentence =
        { "l" }
        { "t" }
      if$ change.case$
      "edition" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.edition *
    }
  if$
}
INTEGERS { multiresult }
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { duplicate$ multi.page.check
        {
          bbl.pages swap$
          n.dashify
        }
        {
          bbl.page swap$
        }
      if$
      tie.or.space.prefix
      "pages" bibinfo.check
      * *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ", " *
          swap$
          n.dashify
          "pages" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.eid}
{ eid "eid" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
      {
          ", " *
      }
      if$
      swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  bolden
  eid empty$
    { format.journal.pages }
    { format.journal.eid }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { bbl.chapter }
        { type "l" change.case$
          "type" bibinfo.check
        }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.prefix
      "chapter" bibinfo.check
      * *
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {bt.enquote}
{ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
  { "\enquote{" swap$ *
    non.stop
      { ",} " * }
      { "}, " * }
    if$
  }
  if$
}
%% Added 3 April 2018
FUNCTION {bt.emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
  { "\emph{" swap$ *
    non.stop
      { ",} " * }
      { "}, " * }
    if$
  }
  if$
}
%% Changed to italics (emphasise) April 3 2018
FUNCTION {format.booktitle}
{
  booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check
%  bt.enquote
%  bt.emphasize
}
%% Removed extra comma before volume May 28 2018
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      format.bvolume duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        %{ ", " swap$ * * }
        { " " swap$ * * }
      if$
      editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        {
          get.bbl.editor
          swap$ "," *
          " " * swap$ *
          swap$
          " " * swap$
          * }
      if$
      word.in swap$ *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.month}
{
  month empty$
    { "" }
    { " " month * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    { swap$ pop$
      "t" change.case$ "type" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ number "number" bibinfo.check
  type duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ bbl.techrep }
    'skip$
  if$
  "type" bibinfo.check
  swap$ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "t" change.case$ }
    { tie.or.space.prefix * * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
  key duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$
      journal duplicate$ empty$
        { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref * warning$ }
        { "journal" bibinfo.check emphasize word.in swap$ * }
      if$
    }
    { word.in swap$ * " " *}
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  "editor" bibinfo.check
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      "editor" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.etal
      emphasize
      *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              "editor" bibinfo.check
              " " * bbl.etal
              emphasize
              *
            }
            {
             bbl.and space.word
              * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              "editor" bibinfo.check
              *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref " * crossref * warning$
      pop$ word.in
    }
    { bbl.volume
      swap$ tie.or.space.prefix "volume" bibinfo.check * * bbl.of space.word *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { series empty$
            { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              "" *
            }
            { series emphasize * }
          if$
        }
        { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$
            { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
            }
            { word.in swap$ * }
          if$
        }
        { word.in key * " " *}
      if$
    }
    { word.in format.crossref.editor * " " *}
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      add.blank "(" *
      t empty$
        { address "address" bibinfo.check *
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
          if$
        }
      if$
      year empty$
        'skip$
        { t empty$ address empty$ and
            'skip$
            { 
              ", " *                 %% originally: ", " swap$ * *
            }
          if$
          year "year" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
      ")" *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
}

%% Italicized journal title 28 May 2018
FUNCTION {format.journal}
{ "{\protect\JournalTitle{" journal * "}}" *
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  crossref missing$
    {
%%      journal
%%      "journal" bibinfo.check
%%     "journal" output.check
%%%%%%% Use jabbrv to abbreviate
      format.journal "journal" bibinfo.check "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date output
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    {
      format.publisher.address output
      format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      format.number.series output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      end.quote.btitle
      format.publisher.address output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      format.edition output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title

     format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      end.quote.btitle 
    format.bvolume output.check
    format.edition output
    %"edition" bibinfo.check output
    format.date "year" output.check
    new.sentence
    %format.note output
    fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }
FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { organization "organization" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { output
          address "address" bibinfo.check output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
        {
          address "address" bibinfo.check output
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    {
      organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
      address "address" bibinfo.check output
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title
  "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  bbl.mthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  format.title output
  end.quote.title
  format.note output
  format.date output
  new.sentence

  fin.entry

}


FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title
  "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  bbl.phdthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output

  format.date "year" output.check
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title

     format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      end.quote.btitle 
    format.bvolume output.check
    format.edition output
  editor empty$
    { publisher empty$
        'skip$
        {
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { publisher empty$
        {
          format.organization.address output }
        {
          organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
     }
  if$
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title
  "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  format.date output
  new.sentence
  format.note "note" output.check
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
STRINGS { longest.label }
INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }
FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}
FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}
EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}
ITERATE {longest.label.pass}
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" *
  write$ newline$
  "\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}"
  write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {end.bib}
%% End of customized bst file
%%
%% End of file `osajnl2.bst'.
```

Comment: you still haven't provided anything to let anyone reproduce the error, you should be able to take your document and cut it down to a test document with just a single `\cite` and a bib file with a single entry that produces that error in bibtex.

Comment: Doesn't the `proceedings` function do what you want? You can alias it to `inproceedings` using `FUNCTION {inproceedings} {proceedings}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `output.check` incorrectly. The syntax for `output.check` is:

```
some.function "fieldname" output.check
```

`some.function` will process some field in your bib entry and leave that entry to be output, or an empty string. `output.check` will take that and the `"fieldname"` and check the output of `some.function`. If it is empty then a warning is issued (`empty fieldname in <bib entry>`), otherwise the field is output. See a detailed explanation in [What does output.check do in a .bst file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464387/134574)

However you didn't put the `"fieldname"` on the stack, so your stack is one item short, and when `output.check` tries to take the second item from there, it finds the stack empty, thus the error `You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry <bib entry>`.

Correct the line that reads `format.bvolume output.check` to be:

```
format.bvolume "volume" output.check
```